# How to do Dynamic selection of output kafka topics

Tags: apache-flink

I have a very high volume kafka topic. We want to implement a general purpose filtering mechanism that is totally config driven.

Requirements:

- Consumers register a <predicate, topic> combo in a global data store.
- The flink app should regularly read from this config store. THis is the routing table.

At runtime:

```
for each (event) {
   if (predicate(event) == true) {
        send_event_to_topic(event, topic)
   }
```

And do this for every predicate in the config store that matches the event.

How would we make this work, given that in Flink, the kafka topic name in the sink has to be specified up front, and cannot be dynamically determined per event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've encountered something similar to this a while back (the need for dynamic syncing, specifically to Elasticsearch) which involved creating a wrapper that kept track of multiple different sinks and using them based on the incoming message.

This would essentially create a hashmap that would relate a given dynamic topic (key) with the associated sink to handle performing the write operation to the topic.

An implementation for Kafka might look something like this:

```
class DynamicSink<ElementT, RouteT, SinkT : KafkaSink<ElementT, out AutoCloseable>>(
    /**
     * Defines a router that maps an element to its corresponding KafkaSink instance
     * @param sinkRouter A [KafkaSinkRouter] that takes an element of type [ElementT], a string-based route
     * defined as [RouteT] which is used for caching sinks, and finally the sink itself as [KafkaSink]
     */
    private val sinkRouter: KafkaSinkRouter<ElementT, RouteT, SinkT>
) : RichSinkFunction<ElementT>(), CheckpointedFunction {

    // Store a reference to all the current routes
    private val sinkRoutes: MutableMap<RouteT, SinkT> = ConcurrentHashMap()
    private lateinit var configuration: Configuration

    override fun open(parameters: Configuration) {
        configuration = parameters
    }

    override fun invoke(value: ElementT, context: SinkFunction.Context) {
        val route = sinkRouter.getRoute(value)
        var sink = sinkRoutes[route]
        if (sink == null) {
            // Build a new sink for this key and cache it for later use
            sink = sinkRouter.createSink(route, value)
            sink.runtimeContext = runtimeContext
            sink.open(configuration)
            sinkRoutes[route] = sink
        }

        sink.invoke(value, context)
    }

    override fun initializeState(context: FunctionInitializationContext) {
        // No-op.
    }

    override fun snapshotState(context: FunctionSnapshotContext) {
        // Flush any pending writes for
        for (sink in sinkRoutes.values) {
            sink.snapshotState(context)
        }
    }

    override fun close() {
        for (sink in sinkRoutes.values) {
            sink.close()
        }
    }
}
```

The router used above would be responsible for taking an element and determining how it needed to be routed (e.g. determine the topic to route to):

```
/* Example interface */
interface KafkaSinkRouter<ElementT, RouteT, SinkT : KafkaSink<ElementT, *>> {
    fun getRoute(element: ElementT): RouteT
    fun createSink(cacheKey: RouteT, element: ElementT): SinkT
}

/* Example implementation */
class ExampleKafkaRouter(
    private val parameters: ParameterTool
): KafkaSinkRouter<ExampleClass, String, KafkaSink<JsonObject>>, Serializable {
    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this::class.java)

    override fun createSink(cacheKey: String, element: ExampleClass): KafkaSink<ExampleClass> {
        return buildSinkFromRoute(element)
    }

    override fun getRoute(element: YourClass): String {
        return getTopic(element)
    }

    private fun buildSinkFromRoute(element: JsonObject): KafkaSink<ExampleClass> {
        /* Construct a KafkaSink here that points to your target topic */
    }
    
    private fun getTopic(element: ExampleClass): String {
        /* Resolve your topic from your element here */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a prefix for all the topics that you want Flink to read from?
That way, you can use the topicPattern functionality of Kafka Consumer

KafkaSource.builder().setTopicPattern("topic.*")